# Persistent focus in NextJS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js

I'm building my first NextJS site and have come up against some weird behaviour.

My site header is just a number of `<Link />` components that link to various pages of my site. The links have simple focus styles applied in CSS using the `:focus` selector.

When you click on one of the links the focus styles apply as expected and the site navigates to the new URL, however, the focus styles persist even after the new page has loaded.

Is there a way to remove the focus state on transition to a new page?

Hope someone can help a NextJS newbie. Thanks.

Comment: This should not be the case and cannot replicate this behavior. We will need to see more code to advise.

Comment: I don't have the code right now but the site can be viewed here: https://learnnavigation.vercel.app

Comment: I cannot replicate the issue using chrome - assume you resolved it

Comment: No, I haven't resolved it. I've seen the behaviour in Chrome desktop on MacOS and chrome on Android. In fact I've never seen it work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the issue so will post here for anyone having a similar problem in future.

My header links were in my custom `_app.js` file which doesn't get re-rendered and as such the focus state persisted. The solution was to move my site boilerplate out of `_app.js` and place it in it's own component which then wraps each page.

e.g.

**pages/_app.js**

```
const App = ({ Component, pageProps }) => <Component {...pageProps} />;

export default App;
```

**components/SiteLayout.js**

```
import Head from "next/head";

const SiteLayout = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <meta charSet="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
        <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
      </Head>
      <header>
        <Link href="my-page">
          <a>My page</a>
        </Link>
      </header>
      <main role="main">
        {children}
      </main>
    </>
  );
};

export default SiteLayout;
```

**pages/my-page.js**

```
import SiteLayout from "components/SiteLayout";

const MyPage = () => (
  <SiteLayout>
    <h1>My Page</h1>
  </SiteLayout>
);

export default MyPage;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this works. Put an input with height and width of 0, and focus to it while changing url.

```
import { withRouter } from 'next/router';
import React, { createRef, Component } from 'react';

class MyComponent extends Component {

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if (this.props.router != prevProps.router) {
            this.input_ref.focus();
        }
    }

    input_ref = createRef()

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                {/* ... */}

                <input ref={this.input_ref} style={{width: 0, height: 0}} />

                {/* ... */}
            </>
        )
    }
}

export default withRouter(MyComponent);
```